# URL WebView Swift Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am hoping someone maybe able to help, I am new too Xcode and have been trying relentlessly to execute the following URL in webview and not having much luck:

http://view.vzaar.com/5532785/player

Below is the code:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://view.vzaar.com/5532785/player")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

If you using Xcode 7(swift 2). Add following details in your plist

[image]

Comment: @JonAtkins, 1) Select your project name on the left side(Project navigator), 2) Then select info tab on the top, 3) add key as show img